Representing Vector Norm Through Operator Norms
Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $v\in V$. We endow $V$ with a norm $\|\cdot\|_V$ and $\mathbb R$ with the standard norm. I am trying to prove
\begin{equation}
\sup \{\lvert Lv\rvert \mid L\in \operatorname{Hom}(V,\mathbb R), \| L\| \leq 1\} = \|v\|_V.
\end{equation}
Where $\| L\|$ constitutes the operator norm of $L$. I managed to prove '$\leq$' and from my understanding I should now find a specific $L_v\in\operatorname{Hom}(V,\mathbb R)$ where this upper bound is attained. However, I am struggling to do so, especially under the constraint that the operator norm should be bounded by $1$.
Any help is appreciated.

The other direction is difficult to prove by yourself unless you know about the Hahn-Banach theorems. One form states that for each $v\in V\setminus \{0\}$ there exists some $L\in V^{*}$ with $\|L\| = 1$ such that $L(v) = \|v\|$. The result follows from this.
